# What does "if1@if2" mean in interface name in output of "ip address" command on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, container, interface

What does at sign (@) mean in interface name in output of "ip address" command (or the "ip link" command) on Ubuntu, for example interface name "eth0@if44" in the following output:

```
root@aafa1fc24a0b:/# ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
3: ip6tnl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1452 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
    link/tunnel6 :: brd ::
43: eth0@if44: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:12:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.18.0.2/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Additional relevant information:

- This is on Ubuntu 16.04
- Running inside a docker container
- The container is attached to a user-defined bridge
- The interface in question (eth0@if44) is not a VLAN

The setup was created as follows:

```
docker network create my-bridge
docker run --name my-container-1 --network my-bridge --detach --tty ubuntu:16.04 sleep infinity
docker run --name my-container-2 --network my-bridge --detach --tty ubuntu:16.04 sleep infinity
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This represents the link's peer interface index. Although this property appears to be available for any interface, it makes sense for only a few interface types : veth, macvlan, vlan (sub-interface), ... because they have a relation to an other interface.

Any given interface has an index that can be read for example there:

```
/sys/class/net/<interface>/ifindex
```

Its peer link interface can be read there:

```
/sys/class/net/<interface>/iflink
```

Apparently, if it doesn't make sense, the parameter still exists, but is the same as *ifindex*. That would be the case for usual normal or simple interfaces (real hardware eth0, wlan0, dummy0, ...)

The `ip link` commands just interprets the *iflink* value:

- if *iflink* is 0 (apparently for ipip tunnels, which also behave strangely with net namespaces), it will print `@NONE`
- if *iflink* doesn't have matching *ifindex*, it will display `@ifXX` with `XX` being *ifindex*. Not having a matching *ifindex* is enough to know it's related to an other net namespace, see later.
- if *iflink* is itself (*iflink* == *ifindex*) It will not display any `@`. That's what should happen with real interfaces (eth0 ...) but can also be a bug (see later).
- if *iflink* has a matching *ifindex*, it will display this index' name.

When wouldn't it find a matching *ifindex*? When that interface is in an *other network namespace*. This is known because of the `link-netnsid` appended at the end of the result. This value isn't easily available outside of `ip link` (see this Q/A: [How to find the network namespace of a veth peer ifindex?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441876/how-to-find-the-network-namespace-of-a-veth-peer-ifindex)). It reprensents the *locally assigned* nsid of the corresponding peer network namespace. For a container, the first (and probably only) value of 0 will almost always represent the host's net namespace. For an host, there will probably be one link-netnsid value per container, with the first container's link-netnsid being 0. Note that this value is local to the net namespace, not an absolute id, so it can't be compared directly between two net namespaces (see [previous link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441876/how-to-find-the-network-namespace-of-a-veth-peer-ifindex)).

So not finding an *ifindex* certainly means it's in an other namespace. It's confirmed by the presence of a `link-netnsid` property.

Sometimes the *iflink*, that is the index value of the *peer* interface, when in an other net namespace, happens to have the same id as the local interface (in the current net namespace). `ip link` will not display any `@` in this case, with the logic that it's a common interface, but that would wrong, as in this case:

```
# ip -o link show dev veth1
3: veth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000\    link/ether 7e:d9:ca:77:87:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
# cat /sys/class/net/veth1/{ifindex,iflink}
3
3
```

(note the presence of `link-netnsid 0` meaning the link is in an other net namespace.)

In other cases (that I didn't manage to reproduce, so it was perhaps corrected) it might even display a local interface name using the other net namespace index.

For your example, if you run on the host (not in the container): `ip -o link |grep ^44:`. You will most certainly find an interface with index 44, which is the peer's veth link. (Unless there's an intermediate invisible net namespace).

Comment: Thank you for a very clear answer. As you hypothesized, there was indeed a veth interface with index 44 in the host (a Moby VM on MacOS): 

44: veth134a6e9@if43: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-e599a65c40f6 state UP 
    link/ether 06:a2:00:a8:dc:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::4a2:ff:fea8:dc93/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever