# How to implement iptables on lxc-container?

Tags: linux, fedora, iptables, firewall, lxc

I installed lxc-container (fedora 29 amd64) on my ubuntu 18.04 system. The linux container had no firewall command line tools. Therefore I installed iptables into my container and it installed successfully.

However I tried to configure the interfaces to drop all incoming and outgoing packets which did not work. I am giving you all the details here.

The command `ip \a` gave;

```
[root@fedora29 ~]# ip \a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: eth0@if8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:4c:d8:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.0.3.52/24 brd 10.0.3.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 3456sec preferred_lft 3456sec
    inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fe4c:d8bf/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I have iptables rules as follows;

```
[root@fedora29 ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Therefore I added the following two rules

```
iptables --table filter --append INPUT --in-interface eth0@if8 --jump DROP
iptables --table filter --append OUTPUT --out-interface eth0@if8 --jump DROP
```

When I finally saved the configuration with

```
 iptables-save
```

```
[root@fedora29 ~]# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.0 on Wed Feb 20 08:41:43 2019
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -i eth0@if8 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -o eth0@if8 -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Feb 20 08:41:43 2019
```

However the same worked fine with my ubuntu host system, where the interface is named lxcbr0.

Comment: have you reloaded the iptables service after saving? `systemctl iptables reload`

Comment: @RobotJohnny It's giving `. Failed to reload iptables.service: Unit iptables.service not found. `

Comment: What do you think is the result of `ip \a` in contrast to `ip a`?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `@if8` from the interface name in your rules, because it's not part of the interface name. The interface name is just `eth0`.

`@if8` is a clue given about the link peer interface, and is dynamic: for example it could change after container restart.

For more information on the meaning of `@if8` you can see my answer there:
[What does “if1@if2” mean in interface name in output of “ip address” command on Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444892/what-does-if1if2-mean-in-interface-name-in-output-of-ip-address-command-on/444911#444911)

Comment: this solved my problem. I don't know how to mark this answer as solved. Thank you very much. I just omitted @if8 in the iptables of fedora29 lxc and it worked like charm. The other issue is that when i tried to implement `. systemctl reload iptables `. it gave me an error that ` Failed to reload iptables.service: Unit iptables.service not found .`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I need to thank @A.B for his response as it cleared my issue. While I tried using policy for the built-in chain without giving the interface it worked.....

```
[root@fedora29 ~]# iptables --table filter --policy INPUT DROP
[root@fedora29 ~]# iptables --table filter --policy OUTPUT DROP
[root@fedora29 ~]# iptables-save > /etc/network/iptables 
[root@fedora29 ~]# iptables-apply /etc/network/iptables 
Applying new ruleset... done.
Can you establish NEW connections to the machine? (y/N) y
... then my job is done. See you next time.
```

However when i tried to list the rules using `iptables -L` i did observe that no new rules were created but the policy of the rules are modified as shown...

```
[root@fedora29 ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
[root@fedora29 ~]# ping 10.0.3.1
PING 10.0.3.1 (10.0.3.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted

--- 10.0.3.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 23ms

[root@fedora29 ~]# iptables -S
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT DROP
```

Comment: Without knowing the content of `/etc/network/iptables` this is not really helpful. Let alone that it is not an answer but should have been an edit of your question...