# How to find total active namespaces in linux?

Tags: linux, cgroups, namespace

Is there any way to find how many active namespaces of each type are present in Linux? Such as:

- mount ns: 20
- net ns: 40
- etc.

Answer (score 4):

This will iterate over the links under `/proc/*/ns` to count the number of active namespaces of each type, *i.e.* namespaces containing at least one process:

```
sudo find /proc/*/ns -type l -printf "%l\n" |
gawk -F'[:\\[\\]]+' '{ nss[$1][$2] = 1 } END { for (ns in nss) { print ns ": " length(nss[ns]) } }'
```

It works by counting the number of distinct identifiers, grouped by namespace type.

Namespaces can be kept alive without processes by bind mounting them elsewhere; the above doesn’t take this into account.

Comment: Since the docs say so, and I have container setups which rely on that, I know that namespaces can be maintained using bind mounts even if no process is tied to them (the namespaces, not the mounts).

Comment: How would you rephrase “[Bind mounting (see mount(2)) one of the files in this directory to
       somewhere else in the filesystem keeps the corresponding namespace of
       the process specified by pid alive even if all processes currently in
       the namespace terminate.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html)”?

Comment: The bind-mounted namespaces are seen in /proc/mounts (as a nsfs filesystem). eg: `ip netns add test; grep nsfs /proc/mounts`. Then they can be accounted with their inode (eg: `stat -c %i /run/netns/test`) which is the identifier.

Comment: But I admit some might not be so easily accessible when mounted within other mount namespaces...

Comment: There are also fds keeping a namespace alive. If you're interested, in order to solve (only) the network namespace case, I wrote an answer trying to find all 3 categories: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505112/how-do-i-find-all-interfaces-that-have-been-configured-in-linux-including-those/505978#505978  (example for this 3rd category is Firefox)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `lsns(1)` command from the util-linux package for that [1]:

```
lsns -n | awk '{n[$2]++}END{for(k in n) print k"\t"n[k]}'
net     2
cgroup  1
...
```

**But `lsns` is broken**: it won't show either the per-thread namespaces or those only kept alive by an open handle or a bind mount. To get all that, try the `lsnsx.pl` script from my other [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/556725/308316):

```
# perl ./lsnsx.pl | grep -v '^ '
cgroup   1
ipc      1
mnt      3
net      5
...
```

[1] If you're on a machine without `lsns` (eg. busybox), you can extract that info directly from `/proc/*/ns/*`:

```
for f in /proc/[0-9]*/ns/*; do readlink "$f"; done | awk -F: '!t[$2]++{c[$1]++}END{for(k in c)print k"\t"c[k]}'
```

You can change `/proc/[0-9]*/ns` to `/proc/[0-9]*/task/[0-9]*/ns` to also get the per-thread namespaces, but on any moderately-used machine it will get horribly slow.